# How to merge 2 arrays into third array

Tags: arrays, ruby, merge

I have 2 arrays in ruby

```
firstarray = ["1212","3434"]
secondarray = ["9999","6666","7777"]
```

I want to merge these 2 arrays into thirdarray and thirdarray should have following structure-

```
thirdarray = ["1212","3434","9999","6666","7777"]
```

I was planning to use this:

`thirdarray = [firstarray, secondarray.join(", ")]`

but this gives me below which does not have " " around individual values 9999, 6666, 7777.

```
["1212", "3434", "9999 , 6666 , 7777"]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the `+` operator on those two arrays.

```
firstarray = ["1212","3434"]
secondarray = ["9999","6666","7777"]

thirdarray = firstarray + secondarray

=> ["1212", "3434", "9999", "6666", "7777"]
```

Comment: what if I have to populate an array with this secondarray and 2 strings?eg - thirdarray = String2 + String3+ secondarray

Comment: You could use the splat operator: `thirdarray = [*secondarray, "String2", "String3"]`

Comment: @user6378152 If this doesn't answer your question then please edit it and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use concat operator.

Below edits your 'firstarray' by appending your 'secondarray' elements to the end of 'firstarray'. concat is more performant than '+'

```
firstarray.concat(secondarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
> thirdarray = [*firstarray, *secondarray]
#=> ["1212", "3434", "9999", "6666", "7777"]
```

if you want to add extra elements:

```
> thirdarray = [*firstarray, *secondarray, "additional-1" ]
#=> ["1212", "3434", "9999", "6666", "7777", "additional-1"]
```